# Is there a place where I can download Angular Material styles?

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, angular-material-stepper

I'm working my way through an implementation of Angular Material's Stepper, and I want to use the out-of-the-box styles... is there a place I can download them?

I've tried copying & pasting styles from the Angular Material example page... but that will be an extremely tedious process.

Comment: Thanks @christopher, that did the trick! I figured they had to be somewhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use npm or yarn to install Angular Material, the prebuilt themes are available under:

> node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/

For instructions on setting up Angular Material, see: [Getting started](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started)

To define a custom theme, see: [Defining a custom theme](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#defining-a-custom-theme)